# Stakeholder identification and communication methods in UX

Tags: requirements, project

Can any one suggest few existing methods for identifying/communicating stakeholders in user experience design?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It's quite an odd question, since stakeholders and/or sponsors usually fund and initiate projects. If the stakeholders are unknown, and you have no customer party to talk to, I don't think you have a project at all.

But "methods for communication" with stakeholders - we have a lot. In the 1990's and before that the [waterfall project methology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_model) was popular. It ment that you defined a scope into great detail and didn't meet each other again until delivery. The methodology have since the early millennium been abandoned, since the customers where unhappy, the consultants where unhappy and it was expensive.

Today the ruling project methodology is [Agile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development). You divide the project scope in one to four week sprints, where you define the scope in the beginning, and show a demo in the end of each sprint. The customer writes use cases for each new sprint, and adds things they where unhappy with in the previous sprint. By using this methodology, customers are happy, consultants are happy and the project meet budget on time. But it does not guarantee that the original scope of the agreement is met, just that the customer are happy with the current solution they get (i e pay their invoices).

Comment: I disagree here. The people who fund the project turn out to be 1-2 stakeholder (groups). A typical mid-size project has 15-20 stakeholder (groups), and all of their goals have to be taken into consideration. Discovering the other 13-19 stakeholders is not easy.

Comment: yes i know that it is kind of very vague question but i am asking it because in other project(Not UX) our stakeholder are usually very clear while on the other end in UX we have lots of unidentified  stakeholder so that's why i am questioning

Answer (score 1):

When I'm working on a project, I work with a core project team and stakeholders. Stakeholders may initiate a project, but they're not always involved day to day (or even week to week). Stakeholders may also be people who haven't initiated thee work but need to be consulted in order for the work to be successful.

Normally, to engage with stakeholders, I interview stakeholders, facilitate workshops and update meetings. At the beginning of a project, I'll interview different stakeholders individually to get a sense of individual perspectives. Then I'll facilitate a workshop so we can build a shared understanding and gather business requirements. Then as we work through the project tasks, we'll engage with stakeholders at a regular interval to give status updates, to do reviews, to ask questions, etc.

Because I'm a consultant, to communicate, I use email, phone calls, in person meetings, and sometimes a site like Basecamp where we can share files and messages.

HTH, 
tP